# Barcode scanner SurfaceView Rectangle

Tags: android, surfaceview, barcode-scanner

I am now developing a barcode scanner application in android.I have achieved the camera part using SurfaceView in android. And i have drawn a rectangle overlay at centre on surfaceview. Now i want the Camera preview frames only through the particular rectangle line drawn. 
  Now it seems i am getting preview frame from the entire surface. I tried to restrict this using setPreviewSize in camera parameters.
But here i am not able to give Previewsize which is not supported by the camera. 
 So how could i achieve this and i want to know how other barcode scanner applications do this?(e.g zxing barcode scanner)

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: Thanks for the reference. As for as i understood, zxing calculates the rectangle using screen resolution and PreviewSizes and process only the rectangle part in PreviewFrame.I am not understood completely , can you explain me? Or is there any simple way to do that?